# Hide order review based on cart items total in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

how Hide order review based on cart items total in WooCommerce ?

i found this code, but i need hide review based on cart items

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping', 'show_hide_shipping_methods' );
function show_hide_shipping_methods( $needs_shipping ) {
    $cart_items_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    if ( $cart_items_total < 40 ) {
        $needs_shipping = false;

        // Optional: Enable shipping address form
        add_filter('woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_true' );
    }

    return $needs_shipping;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```php
// Remove on checkout page
function remove_checkout_totals() {
    $cart_items_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    if ( $cart_items_total < 40 ) {
        // Remove cart totals block
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'remove_checkout_totals', 1 );
```